# dragging shadow coming over in build button of the tab

Tags: android, drag

Using this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

I was dragging/dropping some images and if the images were not in proper location they are moving to original place,but on problem is occurring there, but, if I am running my app in tabs with in build button (inside tab screen) image not only comes over button but also fly back. But this prob is not coming in buid tabs.
What I tried is to set `y` to `-imagesize/2` when it comes on tab button like

```
if(view.getY()>500){
view.setY(view.getY()-view.getHeight()/2)}
```

but still I'm facing the same problem, kindly guide me.
My code is

```
DROPAREA2.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener(context));

ware.setOnClickListener(wareClick);



    final class MyOnLongClickListener implements OnLongClickListener {

    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        MyDragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    dragview = (RelativeLayout) view;

        // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        // dragView = (TextView) view;
                    /*int[] location = new int[2];
        dragview.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        if(location[1]>520){
            dragview.setY(location[1]-60);
        //  flyBackLayout(dragview);
        Log.d("on shadow out of bound", ""+dragview.getY());
    //  dragview.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

        }*/
        return true;
    }
}

private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private static Drawable shadow;
    View myView;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
        super(v);
        myView = v;
    //  shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
        /* dragImgVw.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener()); */

    }
}


    @Override
public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {

    int mCurX = (int) event.getX();
    int mCurY = (int) event.getY();
    // int[] location = null;

    if (event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP
            || event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {

        Log.v("ONDRAGEVENThere", "ONDRAGEVENT it is :: " + mCurX + ", "
                + mCurY);

        View view1 = (View) event.getLocalState();
        view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // /view1.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int[] location = new int[2];
        int[] location1 = new int[2];
        view1.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        ObjectAnimator animationx = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1,
                "translationX", mCurX - view1.getWidth() / 2 - location[0],
                0.0f);
        ObjectAnimator animationy = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1,
                "translationY", mCurY - view1.getHeight() / 2 - location[1]
                        + 10, 0.0f);
        AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animSet.setDuration(500);
        animSet.playTogether(animationx, animationy);

        animSet.start();

    }
            return true;

}


public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {



    MyDragListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            Log.d("ACTION_DRAG_STARTED", "ACTION_DRAG_STARTED" + "");
        //  if(event.getY()>520)

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d("ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED", "ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED" + "");
            /               break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            Log.d("ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION", "ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION" + "");
            int mCurX = (int) event.getX();
            int mCurY = (int) event.getY();

            if (DEBUG)
                Log.v("Cur(X, Y) : ", " CLASSr here ::" + mCurX + ", "
                        + mCurY);

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d("ACTION_DRAG_EXITED", "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED" + "");
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.v("here", "drag exits");
    /               /
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d("ACTION_DROP", "ACTION_DROP" + "");
            // COUNTER=0;
            // handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) event.getLocalState();

            // stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // view dragged item is being dropped on
            RelativeLayout dropTarget = (RelativeLayout) v;

            // view being dragged and dropped
            RelativeLayout dropped = (RelativeLayout) view;

            dropped.setEnabled(false);

            // /////////////////////DROP AREA 4
        //  dropTarget.setText(view.getText());
            dropTarget.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            if (dropTarget.getId() == R.id.relDROPAREA2){
                                            //          //some animation
            }


                break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d("ACTION_DRAG_ENDED", "ACTION_DRAG_ENDED" + "");
                            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }


}
OnClickListener wareClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return false;
        //some animation
    }
};
```

}